# Edit the content of the varible on Twig file

Tags: php, twig

I am new to PHP. I am on a twig file and if I do
{{ dump(content)}}- i get this:-

```
{#1937 ▼
  -id: "387"
  -url: "why-we-are-cool"
  -pagetitle: "Why Book With us?"
  -hidden: false
  -bodytitle: "Why book with us?"
  -desc: "plus a 24/7 support team on the end of the phone – t ▶"
  -keywords: "why us"
  -body: """
    <p>Up to 50% off Smith hotels all year round</p>\r\n
    <a class="button button-primary" href="https://www.google.co.uk">Join the club</a> <a class="button button-primary" href="https://www.google.co.uk ▶
    """
}
```

Now I want to be able to change/add attributes on the a tags above from same twig file. How do I do that? Thanks a lot for your help. Cheers!

Comment: I'm confused. You want to alter the structure of a twig file at runtime, or do you just want to change the data passed into the twig file?

Comment: _"Now I want to be able to change/add attributes on the a tags above"_ - Please give us a proper description and an example of what the result should look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot Magnus Eriksson for editing the file.

Comment: No worries. Now it's up to you to edit it to include more information.

Comment: Yes I want to alter the content of a tagsThis is the data I am getting from the back end. I want to add/override the attributes on twig files.

Comment: What "tags"? Also, why can't you change it in the back end? I'm about to vote to close this question for being unclear...

Comment: The anchor tags that are part of the content.body, say I want to add an event listener or add classes on those anchor tags for example. As I said I am not very comfortable with twig. For now I just want to override the content of content variable

Comment: Twig is a presenation layer, you should not be updating properties of an object /array there though. Either way what type is your variable? an array or an object?